# tick labels have different precision

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks, yticks

When defining tick labels I get an abnormally high level of precision.  For example:

```
import pylab as pl

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(3.25, 2.5))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax0.set_ylim([0, 0.5])
ax0.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 0.51, 0.1), minor=False)
ax0.set_yticklabels(np.arange(0, 0.51, 0.1), fontsize=8)

ax0.set_xlim([0, 0.5])
ax0.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 0.51, 0.1), minor=False)
ax0.set_xticklabels(np.arange(0, 0.51, 0.1), fontsize=8)

fig.show()
```

The output figure is below with the bad tick labels on the 0.3 marker (both x and y axes).  I have tried using np.linspace, which yields the same problem.

I understand the issues with floating point precision, but I would expect the label to be rounded off a lot sooner.  How do I correct this to only show the first decimal?

Using matplotlib 2.2.2
[image: Figure with bad labels.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was struggling with that today, this is my current solution:

v1:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
ax0.set_xlim([0, 0.5])
ax0.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 0.51, 0.1), minor=False)
ax0.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))
```

v2:

```
ax0.set_xlim([0, 0.5])
ax0.set_xticks(np.round(np.arange(0, 0.51, 0.1),2), minor=False)
ax0.set_xticklabels(np.round(np.arange(0, 0.51, 0.1),2), fontsize=8)
```

I'm not sure if the formatter should be before or after the `set_xlim` but this should work :)

Comment: I have never used set_major_formatter before...perhaps I have just been lucky until now.  I am surprised I have not encountered this issue before.

Comment: You need to leave out the line `set_xticklabels`, else it will overwrite the `FormatStrFormatter` with a `FixedFormatter` resulting in the same issue.

Comment: My point is either you leave out the line with `set_major_formatter` or the one with `set_xticklabels`. Whatever comes last, overwrites the former.

Comment: noted, just shared my implementation since I lost my mind trying to make it behave properly and that's what worked. Now that I'm calmed I can make sense of what you mention :)

Answer (score 0):

The ticks will be automatically labelled correctly if you don't set them manually

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3.25, 2.5))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax0.set_ylim([0, 0.5])
ax0.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 0.51, 0.1), minor=False)

ax0.set_xlim([0, 0.5])
ax0.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 0.51, 0.1), minor=False)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is completely irrelevant.